# How to avoid this error: "Took too long to show custom notification. Falling back to static."?

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit

Having issues testing out the custom long look notification on the apple watch simulator. The debugger log this error:

```
WatchKit Extension[5230:156324] Took too long to show custom notification. Falling back to static.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I too have the same issue.I only have the default code.Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly this problem with the default code set up by Xcode. I didn't do any operations inside didReceiveRemoteNotification, but the error still occured.

Turns out the reason it failed was that my WKUserNotificationInterfaceController subclass **was not connected to the Dynamic interface Controller in my storyboard file**.

*Solution:*

1. Go to the storyboard file for your watchkit app.
2. Click on your Dynamic Interface controller
3. Click the identity inspector (middle tab in the right pane)
4. In the Class field, select your
   WKUserNotificationInterfaceController subclass (xcode had named mine
   NotificationController)
5. Voilà!

[image: Make sure your WKUserNotificationInterfaceController subclass is linked to your dynamic interface controller in the Identity inspector!]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before.
Inside didReceiveRemoteNotification, are you calling          `completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);`  ?
Also, what are you doing inside that function? If takes too much time, it will show by default the static notification:

> "Use the static notification interface to define a simple version of
>   your custom notification interface. The purpose of a static interface
>   is to provide a fallback interface in the event that your WatchKit
>   extension is unable to configure the dynamic interface in a timely
>   manner"

Comment: Hi @Javier Flores Font, I only have this code "completionHandler(.Custom)" in the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method. I'm not doing anything that takes too much time. Still couldn't figure out how to solve this issue...

Comment: As Javier said, don´t do anything that takes time, basically. Try to comment all your code and just call completionHandler(.Custom). Then step by step comment code in. Basically, do near-to-nothing. Take information out of the notification, fill your UI, that´s all. No image fetching, Object generation etc. -> that all takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your custom class name as `NotificationController`. Xcode take it as `WKUserNotificationcontroller`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you take too long in your handler to setup. If it takes too long, the watch will default to the static notification.

Be sure you are calling the correct completion block:

```
completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
```

*When calling the completion handler block, if you want WatchKit to display your static interface instead, specify the WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeDefault constant.*

Reference: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html

Comment: Hi EhTd, I only have this code "completionHandler(.Custom)" in the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method. I'm not doing anything that takes too much time. Still couldn't figure out how to solve this issue...

Comment: @user1872384 I think I have the same problem as you. I don't have anything in "didReceiveRemoteNotification" besides the completion handler but I can't get past the error. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the created WatchKit Extension was configured as Swift code, while my entire project was in Objective-C.

The Dynamic Interface never show up, always switching to the Static one printing the error of this post in the console. Once I changed the WatchKit Extension to Objective-C everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a real watch, try turn off "Wrist Detection" in "Watch" -> "General".