# Apple Watch Notification Payload

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, watchkit

I want to add values to the apple watch notification (the current screen uses hard coded data):

[image]

The values I want to add are for these fields: "Amount", "At" and "When". How can I add get this values from the PushNotificationPayload.apns file and show it on the notification?

This is the PushNotificationPayload.apns file:

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "body": "New Transaction\n\n",
        "title": "Optional title"
    },
    "category": "newTransactionCategory"
},

"WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
                               {
                               "title": "Details",
                               "identifier": "transactionDetailsButtonAction"
                               }
                               ],

"customKey": "Use this file to define a testing payload for your notifications. The aps dictionary specifies the category, alert text and title. The WatchKit Simulator Actions array can provide info for one or more action buttons in addition to the standard Dismiss button. Any other top level keys are custom payload. If you have multiple such JSON files in your project, you'll be able to select them when choosing to debug the notification interface of your Watch App."
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps,

- Create a new class which is a subclass of `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController`.
- From the storyboard, select your Dynamic Interface Scene for notification (if you have not created it, enable 'Has Dynamic Interface' in attribute inspector of your Static Scene ) and in Identity Inspector set custom class as created above.
- Now modify your PushNotificationPayload.apns file contents as below,

  ```
  {
      "aps": {
          "alert": {
              "body": "New Transaction\n\n",
              "title": "Optional title"
          },
          "category": "newTransactionCategory"
      },

      "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
                                     {
                                     "title": "Details",
                                     "identifier": "transactionDetailsButtonAction"
                                     }
                                     ],

      "Amount": "USD 20",
      "At": "Mc Donalds",
      "When": "Today",
  }
  ```
- When a remote notification is received, this method will be called in your custom notification interface class and you will receive the custom keys in the dictionary 'remoteNotification' which you need to use to set the text of your labels here.

  ```
  -(void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler {
      NSLog(@"remoteNotification Dictionary %@",remoteNotification);

      completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
  }
  ```
- Last is debugging:

  1. Select your targets on the top and select Edit Scheme
  2. Click on duplicate scheme at the bottom and give your custom name like 'NOTIFICATION-Mywatchkitapp' etc...
  3. Then, select WatchKit Interface to Dynamic Notification, Notification Payload to your PushNotificationPayload.apns file and run for this target.

Comment: Hi @DH14-S L, I would like to try out your solution. However currently I'm having issue running the custom long-look notification. I've posted the error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341051/how-to-avoid-this-error-took-too-long-to-show-custom-notification-falling-bac/29345228#29345228

Comment: Make sure that 'category' key is correct in Storyboard and Payload. Then check if you have not written any long running code on 'willActivate'.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not solve the error. :( Even creating a new project and setup a new watchkit target with custom notification enabled will give that error as well... This is so frustrating....

Comment: Question. I have this woking well with various categories for testing apns. But I'm curious as to how a real-world notification from the server would be delivered. i.e. if the server is a C++ (or other) server what is the mechanism that gets the notification from the server to the actual device? Simply the Apple server with our dev certificate? How can we test real-world notifications via TestFlight (or other method)?

Comment: I set up my .apns file like this, but in the watch kit notification interface method didReceive(notification:), the notification does not contain `Amount`, `At` and `When`. Any tips?